# Phone Number Regex Validation error while showing/hiding Elements

Tags: javascript, validation, input

I am working on a form where I am showing a div when a user submits the form and it checks if all the fields values are not blank. I have achieved that part and it is working fine.
Now the problem is when I am validating the phone number using regex, it is showing error but still displays the div and form is also submitted successfully. It should not get submit till the user enters a correct phone number, it gives an error and still, the form gets submitted. I know the error is there but I am not understanding where I am wrong. Please guide me.

```js
function mySub() {
  const user = document.getElementById('pmname').value.trim();
  const uemail = document.getElementById('pmemail').value.trim();
  const uphone = document.getElementById('pmphone').value.trim();
  const uregx = /^[0-9]{10}$/;
  const upmmb = uregx.test(uphone);
  if (user == "" || uemail == "" || uphone == "" || upmmb == "") {
    document.getElementById('agy').style.display = 'none';
    alert("Enter Valid Mobile Number");
    document.getElementById('pmphone').focus();
  } else {
    document.getElementById('agy').style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

```css
#agy {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="#">
  <div id="agy">
    <div class="agent-details">
      <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
        <div class="agent-image">
          <img class="rounded" src="#" alt="Jazz" width="70" height="70" />
        </div>
        <ul class="agent-information list-unstyled">
          <li class="agent-name"><i class="houzez-icon icon-single-neutral mr-1"></i> Jazz</li>
          <li class="agent-link"><a href="#">View Listings</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" name="name" id="pmname" value="" type="text" placeholder="Name" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" name="mobile" id="pmphone" value="" type="text" placeholder="Phone" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" name="email" id="pmemail" value="" type="email" placeholder="Email" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group form-group-textarea">
    <textarea class="form-control hz-form-message" name="message" rows="4" placeholder="Message">Hello, I am interested in ...</textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control control--checkbox m-0 hz-terms-of-use">
      <input type="checkbox" id="ppa" name="privacy_policy" checked="" />By submitting this form I agree to <a target="_blank" href="https://propertymakkerz.com/pm/property/sai-ashishkaranjadepanvel/">Terms of Use</a>
      <span class="control__indicator"></span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form_messages"></div>
  <button type="button" class="houzez_agent_property_form btn btn-secondary btn-full-width" onclick="mySub()"><span class="btn-loader houzez-loader-js"></span> Send Message</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Java and JavaScript are completely unrelated languages.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Sorry it was a mistake while selecting tags, I will rectify it

Comment: actually the problem is in your if statement  because you put || condition so if one of these condition is true ,the code inside will execute  .  that mean if the user access his number phone correctly but he didn't access his name the alert message will appear saying 'the phone number is incorrect'

Comment: also you can easily check that the user didn't leave any thing blank by putting 'required' into the html input